# How do you add gitconfig clone functionality to pull the project and wiki in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-config

I have documentation that requires updating in XXX project and, when cloned, I need to also clone the wiki so the documentation can be updated.

So I'm trying to add a clone alias to clone both the XXX and XXX.wiki projects, but that hasn't yielded positive results. Does anyone have a suggestion that might better solve my problem?

I've included this to show one of my many trials, but it in no way reflects the breadth of my attempts.

```sh
[alias]
    cl = !sh -c 'git clone git@git.gitlab.com/$1 $(basename $1)' -
```

Comment: Since the Wiki of a repo lives in its own Git repo, independent from the main Git repo, I'm pretty sure you'll need to separate clone commands to clone them both.

Comment: @joanis yes, I do, but I'm not certain how to construct that. It hasn't been working in the alias. The parsing in sed or awk seems interrupted by the way git reads the gitconfig. Any thoughts on how to approach the issue of constructing a URL for the wiki and, the second issue, maintaining user credentials when cloning, because it seems to drop the credentials off and I dont see a means to tell git to look in my user's .ssh for the keys when trying to clone in this way.

Comment: Yeah, I've just been playing with this, and `sh -c` does weird things with my arguments. I don't really get what's happening. Maybe do this with a bash script instead? That one would be much easier to write...

Comment: So far I have this ugly thing: `cl = !sh -c "true; git clone git@git.gitlab.com/$1; git clone git@git.gitlab.com/$1.wiki; true`, but only the first clone happens. The weird `true` calls in there are just to avoid having spurious arguments given to the `git clone` commands. Ugly, and it doesn't even work!

Comment: @joanis see what I mean!?

Comment: Indeed! But have you tried my answer, or @KamilCuk's? I think both answers will solve your problem.

Comment: @joanis I'm in the process of writing and testing things, in accordance with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite difficult to do with an alias, because Git does strange things with parameters your provide to an alias, which I could not figure out.

However, you can also define a command by creating a script with the right name. `git cl` will invoke `git-cl` if it finds it on your path, and it's a lots easier to solve your problem in a bash script.

So, add a file called `git-cl` to your path, say, in `~/bin`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
git clone git@git.gitlab.com/$1
git clone git@git.gitlab.com/$1.wiki
```

Run `chmod +x ~/bin/git-cl`

And then this should work: `git cl XXX` will clone both XXX and XXX.wiki into your current folder. Adjust the exact commands run in `git-cl` to meet your needs if I didn't get them quite right.

Comment: had to make some modifications, using sed, on your script because $1 is the <project>.git,. the wiki for any project is <project>.wiki.git so $1 wouldn't work, but seems to work now.

Answer (score 3):

> but I'm not certain how to construct that

You can do a function, it's specially handled by `git-alias` code.

```
[alias]
    cl = "!f() { git clone this/\"$1\"; git clone that/\"$1\"; } f"
```

And you can create a file named `git-cl` with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
git clone this/"$1"
git clone that/"$2"
```

and add this file executable permissions and add it to `PATH`. git will automatically pick it up when typing `git cl`.